# Retrieving content within first paragraph tag with JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to return only the text within the first

tags, stripping out the tags themselves...

The HTML is all within a string from an API, so I am escaping it in a React app, but I want to strip out the HTML to teaser a paragraph. Will update post.

```
"content": {
"rendered": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
```

looking at other threads, the below should work, but I don't know how to populate the 2nd arg to replace with the content of the p tags:

```
string.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/);
```

Also, is there a way to limit it to the first paragraph if there is?

Thank you

Comment: jQuery or JavaScript can do this much easier without the use of RegEx's

Comment: Thanks Robert - need a pure JS solution if possible.

Comment: You want to use it on server side with node?

Comment: Pure js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Also it would be helpful to fully describe your issue providing the HTML you are working with.

Comment: Sorry guys, the html is all within a string from an API, so I am escaping it in a React app, but I want to strip out the HTML to teaser a paragraph. Will update post.

Comment: @LeMoi `string.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/, "$1");` would probablyw wokr for you.

Comment: That works nicely, thank you Maciej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/Qil4gF/1) to replace any html tag with it's innerHTML

or this

```js
const getInnerHTML = (data) => {
  const match = data.match(/<(\w+)>(.*?)<\/\1>/)
  if (match){
    return match[2]
  } else throw new Error("not valid data")
}

console.log(getInnerHTML(`<div>this is innerHTML of div</div>`))
console.log(getInnerHTML(`<p>this is innerHTML of p</p>`))
console.log(getInnerHTML(`<p>this is innerHTML of p`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Then don't replace, instead get it :

```js
var str = '<p>Test Text</p>';
var m = str.match(/<p>([\s\S]*)?<\/p>/i)||[];
str = m[1] || '';
console.log(str);
```